# Duplicate Symbols only when building for simlator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When building for a device (ipad 3) my build works find with no warnings or errors, but when building for the iPad or iPhone simulator I receive linker errors like the following:

```
duplicate symbol _CONSTANT_NAME in:
/Users/me/libLibrary.a(FileName.o)
/Users/me/libOtherLibrary.a(OtherFileName.o)
```

The constants are defined like so in header files

```
const int CONSTANT_NAME = 123;
```

I have tried wrapping the constant's in #define tag's like so:

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

const int CONSTANT_NAME = 123;

#endif
```

why does this work fine when building for device but cause issues when building for simulator?

Comment: Much easier to use **#pragma once** though. Don't make a habit of using **#ifndef** because not only is it uglier code but it's not quite as fast compiling either.

Comment: There is a duplication, so you should delete anyone of them and replace that with the other .a in where ever it has been used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler is telling you exactly the correct thing. You are lucky that it's not happening when building to your iPad directly.

In every .m file where you include this header, you create a new and distinct variable with the same name. The compiler can resolve this when linking all these files into a single .a, but when multiple .a files are built and those multiple .a files are linked together, the compiler compiles about duplicate copies.

I would do one of three things:

1. Turn the `const int` into a `#define`. `#define CONSTANT_NAME 123`
2. Add static before `const int`. `static const int CONSTANT_NAME = 123;`
3. Add extern before `const int` and add the real `const int` to a single .m. In .h, `extern const int CONSTANT_NAME;`. In the single .m, `const int CONSTANT_NAME = 123;`.

For the last one, I would create a constants.m file as a separate place to hold the `const int CONSTANT_NAME = 123;` definition.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "The compiler is telling you exactly the correct thing." <--- that. Always important (I forgot today for a few minutes) to read the actual error messages before quickly jumping to search for solutions.

Comment: Is there a better explanation than "luck" for why this is happening only on Simulator? See this question please - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822142/why-is-xcode-flaky-about-throwing-duplicate-symbol-errors

Comment: I'd also like to know why this only happens for the Simulator and why the `#ifdef` thing does not work?